# Send windows messages with Mono

Tags: .net, windows, mono, message-queue, sendmessage

Is it possible to send windows messages (WM_...) to other applications using Mono (assuming that my app is running on Windows)? Another related question is whether there is any way to use DDE inside a Mono app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if I were you I would strarted from

- mono to winapi32
- sending win message using winapi32

So just try any "hello_world" sample.
(I haven't mono right now, sorry for this)

For example you may just compile the following code:

(stolen from http://boycook.wordpress.com/2008/07/29/c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata/)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MessageHelper
{

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, 
ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);
}

//Used for WM_COPYDATA for string messages
public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
   public IntPtr dwData;
   public int cbData;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
   public string lpData;
}
```

I suppose it compiles and it doesn't thow DllNotFoundException or EntryPointNotFoundException when you call

```
MessageHelper.SendMessage(100, 100, new COPYDATASTRUCT());
```

If you have some issue with this... Hmm.. You may tray to load mscorlib.dll at the runtime.
But this way have bad smell.

Also you may find some details here http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

Comment: This qestion is indistinct a bit.
I don't know what you have already and what you actually need.

For example you should receive handler on the window wich will receive your messages.
And also maybe you want to register your own window messages.
Or if you pretty sure that your program will be used on WinXp or higher only you may try to use mscorlib.dll [](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.allowreversepinvokecallsattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

and so on )))

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work even if I use, say, GTK# toolkit right? (Sorry, I'm new to this stuff). Thanks!

Comment: Correct.
GTK# is just a framework.
Some times I playing with mixing mono assemblies with MS.NET assemblies. That worked fine.

In the other hand looks like you want crossplatform app due to you use GTK#. In this case you probably have to use something like dynamic loading. I'm not sure that your app with p/invoke behaviors well on linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a side question, is there similar mechanism for Linux/Mac? Basically, I want to send keypress events to other apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to send WM_* messages to and from Mono on Windows applications exactly like any other Windows application.

Mono Winforms imitates and integrates with the regular Windows message pump when running on Windows.

Comment: @brian ... not sure, but I would doubt apps written for the GTK# toolkit run on Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I think GTK# is cross platform since monodevelop is written on it.

Comment: I assume on some level Gtk+ must be interacting with the Windows message pump, but I do not know how receptive it will be to your custom messages.